# Trying to change Image of every page when i click on link but default image backs every time

Tags: javascript

I want to change header image every time when I click on the link  but my default image comes back every time
I have 2 header file one is for `index.php` and one for all other links

```
<script>     
function _(x){
  return document.getElementById(x);
}
function changeimage(x,imgsrc){
  _(x).src= imgsrc;
}
</script>

<?php
  include ("header.php") 
?> 
  Content here
<?php 
  include ("footer.php") 
?>
```

in header file code is

```
<nav class="nav">
    <img class="small-device-logo" src="../images/logo.png" />
    <ul>
        <li><a href="../index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="changeimage('img1','../images/image2.png');" href="../1.php">4</a></li>
        <li><a class="cssimg" href="2.php">3</a></li>
        <li><a class="jsimg" href="3.php">2</a></li>
        <li><a class="phpimg" href="4.php">1</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>**

<div class="banner">
    <img id="img1" src="../images/banner.png" />
</div>
```

if I use the same code on plain `HTML` file it works but here in `PHP`, it's not working properly.

Comment: Why not use PHP instead? `<img id="img1" src="../images/image<?php echo $pagenumber;?>.png" />`

Answer (score 0):

you set header but you then you go another page. So store your image src in storage and when reload get image src from storage and set it.

```
function changeimage(x, imgsrc) {
  _(x).src= imgsrc; // while the page changes - optional
  localStorage.setItem('imgsrc', imgsrc);
}
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('imgsrc')) {
    _(x).src = localStorage.getItem('imgsrc');
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your page changes before the image is visible

Why not use PHP instead?

`<img id="img1" src="../images/image<?php echo $pagenumber+1;?>.png" />`